# Convert min per km to display on TextView

Tags: android

I developing a run tracker app, I already calculated an average pace that gives me a minute per km time. But now I cant understand how to convert this value to show it in this format 00:00.

This is the relevant method:

```
    private void setPace(double distanceInMeters) {
    double totalTimeinSec = (timer.getTimeInSeconds() + (timer.min * 60));
    double metersPerSecond = (distanceInMeters / totalTimeinSec);
    double minPerKm = 16.6666667 / metersPerSecond;
    // convert minPerKm
}
```

The values that it gives me for example for Duration time: `00:13:07` and distance of `2.02`:

- `totalTimeinSec = 787.0`
- `metersPerSecond = 2.5607004323181384`
- `minPerKm = 6.508635875424163`

I need to convert `minPerKm` to a real time to show it in average pace.
Anyone can help please?

Found the solution!
My corrected code, maybe will help anyone:

```
    private void setPace(double distanceInMeters) {
    double totalTimeinSec = (timer.getTimeInSeconds() + (timer.min * 60));
    double metersPerSecond = (distanceInMeters / totalTimeinSec);
    double minPerKm = 16.6666667 / metersPerSecond;
    double secondsPerKm = minPerKm * 60;
    int sec = (int)(secondsPerKm);
    int min = sec / 60;
    sec %= 60;
    Log.d("PACE","Your pace is: " + String.format("%02d",min) + ":" + String.format("%02d",sec));
    // convert minPerKm
}
```

Comment: You need to convert minPerKm to HH:MM or to MM:SS?

Comment: I want to convert to MM:SS

Comment: minutes are given by dividing `totalTimeinSec` and `60`.

Comment: Thank you! Already found the solution! edited my post